# can anyone help me correct it? it just stops everytime

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, wifi

```
@echo off
IF (netsh wlan connect ssid="SRM HOSTELS" name="SRM HOSTELS") GOTO foundit

GOTO end

:foundit
cd "C:\Users\SATYAM\My-GitHub-REPOSITORIES\SRM WIFI LOGIN"

python SRM-WiFi-Auto-Login.py

:end
```

Comment: The IF command does not work like that.  There is no syntax in the help file that says you can do what you are trying to do so I am not sure where you got that code example.

Comment: Consider using a For /F loop to process the output of the netsh command, then using Find or Findstr on the output to determine if the condition desired is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
netsh wlan connect ssid="SRM HOSTELS" name="SRM HOSTELS" >nul 2>&1
if errorlevel 1 (
  echo not able to connect. Exiting.
  goto :eof
)
echo successfully connected to SRM.
echo Auto-login now...
...
```

First line: try to connect to the WLAN, redirect STDERR and STOUT (all output) to NUL (Nirwana)
Second line: if that failed (no connection), ...
Third to fifth line: ... echo a message and exit.
Sixth line onward: connection was successful, do your auto-login

Answer (score 0):

This is a means by which you can check the output of the netsh command for the string (condition) you wish to test.

The For /F loop stores the output in a tempory file and tests the file for the existence of the desired string.

'&&' executes the Following Command if the Preceeding Commands returns an Errorlevel of 0, which Find returns when it succesfuly finds a string.
This effectively results in a condition check on the output of Find equivalent to:

`If true output of netsh includes String, DO...`

The false / fail actions are positioned to execute immediately should the condition not be true.

```
@echo off

FOR /F "USEBACKQ TOKENS=1,* DELIMS=" %%a IN (`YOUR NETSH COMMAND HERE`) DO (
    ECHO(%%a>>ssidCheck.txt
    FIND /I "YOUR STRING TO FIND HERE" ssidCheck.txt 2>&1>nul && Goto :found
)

:NotFound
ECHO Not found

:cleanup
DEL /Q "ssidCheck.txt"
pause
EXIT

:found
:: REM : Your 'On find, do' actions here.
ECHO found
GOTO :cleanup
```

Comment: what i am actually trying to do is that i have created a program in python with selenium which can connect itself directly to my hostel wifi if it is in range and sign up in it.               so what i am writing in code is:    IF this statement(netsh wlan connect ssid="SRM HOSTELS" name="SRM HOSTELS") is TRUE then DO this(cd "C:\Users\SATYAM\My-GitHub-REPOSITORIES\SRM WIFI LOGIN"

python SRM-WiFi-Auto-Login.py) ELSE END.....can you please help?

Comment: @SatyamGoyal: `netsh wlan connect ssid="SRM HOSTELS" name="SRM HOSTELS"` is not a statement, but a command and therefore will never be `True` or `False`. At best it would return an useful errorlevel.

Comment: @Stephan then how should i proceed to write it? I am facing lots of problem in completing this file. If you can help it would be very helpful.

Comment: @satyamGoyal, perhaps your missing something or my explanation of the above answer is lacking. The For Loop perfoms Your Chosen Netsh command, and Exports the output of the Command to a File. The Find command Searches the Output in the Temporary File For Your Chosen Phrase, and If the phrase is Found, uses the Errorlevel to GOTO a label and perform the commands you want to execute. Together they function as a Conditional Check. - The above is a demonstratation of an approach to Determine your condition, You just need to insert the correct Netsh command and string to Find for your needs.